# Is 802.11n support necessary for a USB wireless adapter？

Tags: usb, wireless-networking, network-adapter, 802.11n

I am considering buy one because my old laptop doesn't contain a WIFI module.

Some adapters support 802.11n and cost more.

802.11n is the newest in 802.11 series.  But I am not sure if 802.11n is going to get popular before I change my laptop next year.

What do u think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your wireless infrastructure. If you don't have a 802.11n Accesspoint, then you don't need the 802.11n adapter. 802.11n pre-standard is around for some time and there are lots of wireless hotspots using it, but it is also backwards compatible to a/b/g.

So, if you have the possiblility to use an 802.11n infrastructure and want to benefit of the new features like more speed, then you should go for the more expensive stick. If you are not sure, which kind of infrastructure you use and if you are happy with it now, then go for the cheaper one. If you use wireless only at home to access your DSL internet connection, then most likely not the wireless infrastructure is the bottleneck

/mspoerr

Answer (score 1):

Get the one with 802.11n. In a couple of years time, you’ll won’t miss that £16 (or whatever the price difference is), but you (or someone else) will be annoyed that their wifi is slower than it could be.